# Is this covariant derivative identity true?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Trying to work through a textbook derivation of the geodesic deviation equation, I've calculated this identity:$$u_{;\beta}^{\alpha}u_{\alpha}=u_{\alpha;\beta}u^{\alpha}.$$

If this is true, I'm making progress. If it isn't, it's back to the drawing board. Does anyone know if it is correct? I've tried writing it out as$$\left(\frac{\partial u^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}+u{}^{\gamma}\Gamma_{\gamma\beta}^{\alpha}\right)u_{\alpha}=\left(\frac{\partial u_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}-u_{\gamma}\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{\gamma}\right)u^{\alpha},$$
 but I'm none the wiser.

Comment: It is true assuming that the connection is the Levi-Civita one, as it is a ``metric'' connection...

Comment: For TeX purposes, you can use `\,` to create a space: `$u^\alpha_{\,;\beta}$` creates $u^\alpha_{\,;\beta}$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Any hints as to how I can show it's true?

Comment: To get the correct spacing regardless of the number of up indices, `$u^\alpha{}_{;\beta}`: $u^\alpha{}_{;\beta}$.

Comment: For a  metric connection $g_{ab}\:_{;c} = 0$

Comment: @Peter4075 the Levi-Civita connection is the unique torsion-free connection such that covariant differentiation and contraction with the metric (i.e. raising and lowering indices) commute. The identity is true because the notion of covariant derivative is chosen so that it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity in question is given as,

$$(\nabla_\beta u^\alpha) u_\alpha=(\nabla_\beta u_\alpha)u^\alpha$$

Expanding the left-hand side, we find,

$$(\nabla_{\beta}u^\alpha)u_\alpha = (\nabla_\beta g^{\alpha \delta}u_\delta)u_\alpha = (u_\delta \nabla_\beta g^{\alpha\delta} + g^{\alpha\delta}\nabla_\beta u_\delta)u_\alpha$$

The Levi-Civita connection is precisely the connection which is compatible with the metric structure; as such parallel transporting two tangent vectors preserves the inner product, so we have,

$$\nabla_\beta g^{\alpha\delta} = 0$$

Hence, for the left-hand side, we are left with a term $u^\alpha \nabla_\beta u_\alpha$. Just a general tip regarding these computations: try to avoid expanding the covariant derivative explicitly in terms of the Christoffel symbols as you have done - there are usually better paths to take, just as one is usually advised not to fully expand commutators most of the time.